# Why does "Clear Local Storage" not work in Fauna GraphQL Playground?

Tags: graphql, faunadb

This is my first try at Fauna, following this tutorial: https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-a-client-serverless-jamstack-app-using-netlify-gatsby-and-fauna/. All goes well and after uploading the example shopnotes.gql file from the Fauna dashboard and inspecting the created documents, I quit for the night. Today I go back to Fauna Playground, but get an error message: "Issues processing last GraphQL query". I'm told to clear out my local storage. But clicking the "Clear Local Storage" does nothing. The page refreshes with the same error. So I'm dead in the water. I thought I'd just delete the database I created to start over, but I can't find a way to delete it! What do I do now?

Comment: Are you still experiencing this? There was a UI bug in GraphQL Playground around the same time you posted this, but it has since been fixed.

Comment: No. I left this and went to another tutorial and created another DB. Then when I went back here, the Clear Local Storage worked. But how do I delete these test DBs from the dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears that the Dashboard problem you encountered has been resolved, I'll answer your question from the comments.

To delete an unwanted database using the Dashboard, follow these steps:

- Visit the Dashboard home page
- Click on the database you want to delete
- Click the "Settings" link beside the database name (near the top)
- Click "Delete". A confirmation popup appears.
- Click "Delete"

Repeats these steps for each database that you want to remove.

Note that deleting a database removes all of its content. There is no user-available way to undelete a database, however our support team might be able to help if you ask right away. Complete removal of document data in storage is handled by a background task, so it may be possible to recover most (if not all) of your content. If you wait 24 hours or more, the data is likely gone.